# how to return decimal value in cpp

Tags: c++, return, decimal

This is my simple program to print pi value from another function (I'm trying to learn function calls). When pi value is given in main(), it shows decimals. But when I try to get it from another function, it shows only 3.

Does "return" returns only integers or is there any thing else?

My Program:

```
int Pi()
{
    float a = 3.14159;
    return a;
}


int main()
{
    float x = Pi();
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5)<< x << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: why int Pi() { .. } and not float Pi() { .. }?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does "return" returns only integers or is there any thing else?

Yes, because you have clearly asked it to do so by writing

```
int Pi()
^^^
```

If you want the function to return `float`, make it do so:

```
float Pi()
^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You're indirectly converting your `float a` to an `int` because you declared your function to return an integer value.

```
int Pi()
```

As Petr pointed out it should be

```
float Pi()
```

or

```
double Pi()
```

If you're new to C++ I highly recommand you to tell your compiler to warn you if you do errors like that. It will help you to notice small errors, wich can be compiled but may result in unwanted behavior. For example if you're using `g++` you could use something like that

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -c -o main main.cpp
```

`Wall` an `Wextra` tell the compiler to warn you when you're making small errors. `Wconversion` is directly to warn you if there is any implicit type conversion (implicit cast).

There are way more warning-flags with g++. May have a look at its manpage ;)

Answer (score 0):

you are return type is int . it is called an implicit cast .you pi float will be converted to an int.

Answer (score -3):

Your function Pi() is of type int so when it returns the value of "a" it converts the float to an int and an int variable cannot have a decimal point so it is changed to 3. Whatever type you make your function will return that type of variable,best practise would be to declare the variable as the type you want to return so that there is no implicit conversion eg

```
string Pi()
    {
        string a = "3.14159";
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: "would return a string with text "3.14159"" --- no, it would not